# Show all posts with zero answers

Tags: support, search

Is there a way to search for all topics that have absolutely no answers? There is a filter for unanswered but that one only lists the topics that don't have an accepted answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use advanced search:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0